Is there any method to compress SDL_Texture object?
As I know that dx and opengl support compressed texture format to reduce storage usage in RAM and in VRAM. However, native SDL_Renderer seems not support compressed texture format so that ~10M of image(.png format) in disk will lead to ~1 GiB memory usage. I have applied object pool to load image resources dynamically but it still ate hundreds MiB of my RAM. Maybe I should turn to opengl implementation but thus I need to refactor planty of functions that implemented by sdlrenderer.
